# Can I check who updated the static front page on WordPress and the time it was done

Tags: customization, frontpage, revisions

I need to check who updated the static front page of a WordPress site and the time it was done. Is it possible? And if so how?

I'm an administrator of the site and there are other administrators with access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some clue using the revision log. For more advanced logs, try using a plugin such [Simple History](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-history/)

Comment: Please post a real answer

Comment: I can't see why this isn't a real answer. The posts revisions should give a clue, but besides that he will need a plugin, like the one I've cited.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to find who changed the static front page from one page to another, not the content that was changed on the page.

Comment: In this case a plugin is in fact the way to go. WordPress keeps no registry of options history.

Comment: I think the answer with Simple History is correct. If you go to Settings -> Reading and change the post for Front Page there, the old page id and the new page id will be logged in Simple history. 

You can see a screenshot of this in action here: http://bit.ly/24om0Ts

(Disclaimer: I am the author of that plugin.)